# An exception about "Partition Routing Information" in reading a document from DocumentDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-cosmosdb

Have you ever seen this exception message?

> Partition routing information cannot be extracted from the query when
>   running in a 32-bit process. To complete your query and avoid this
>   exception, ensure that your host process is 64-bit. For Executable
>   applications, this can be done by unchecking the "Prefer 32-bit"
>   option in the project properties window, on the Build tab.  For VSTest
>   based test projects, this can be done by selecting Test->Test
>   Settings->Default Processor Architecture as X64, from Visual Studio
>   Test menu option. For locally deployed ASP.NET Web applications, this
>   can be done by checking the "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for
>   web sites and projects", under Tools->Options->Projects and
>   Solutions->Web Projects.

When I want to read a document from DocumentDB, I get this exception message. The code in C# to retrieve the document likes the following (without FeedOption have been examined too):

```cs
FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true };
var conv = db.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<Model.Conversation>(
UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(db.DatabaseName, db.CollectionName), queryOptions)
.Where(f => f.Id == "conversationId");

// the exception happens here
foreach(Conversation f in conv)
{
    Debug.Print(f.Name);
}
```

In the above, `db` is a repository and I am sure that the `Client` have been initiated correctly as I can insert a document into DocumentDB in the meanwhile.

Also, you can see the Conversation model:

```cs
public class Conversation
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("cid")]
    public string CID { get; set; } // defined as a partition key
}
```

I should mention that there is a document in DocumentDB with `Id == "conversationId"`, and the following code is working in this situation, but it is not the solution as I want to query on `Name` property too, not just on `Id`:

```cs
Document doc = await db.Client.ReadDocumentAsync(
         UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(db.DatabaseName, db.CollectionName, "conversationId"),
         new RequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("partitionKey") });
Conversation conv = (Conversation)(dynamic)doc;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. In the question, used from 1.11 version of Microsoft.Azure.Document library. As I found in [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.azure.documents.client.documentclient.createdocumentquery.aspx#M:Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery%28System.Uri,Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.FeedOptions%29), `CreateDocumentQuery` has been obsoleted, and apparently the api has been changed.  So, When I downgrade to version 1.10, everythings work fine. Hence, I am so happy about that!

As a result, `CreateDocumentQuery` has been obsoleted in version 1.11 and you should define a partitionKey for each collection, and its result is you can't use `CreateDocumentQuery` anymore, unless you downgrade to 1.10 version or less.
Also, I think it is a bug in this version and should be reported.

Comment: Hi OmG, The API DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery Method (Uri, FeedOptions, Object) was deprecated a while back and it's deprecated in 1.10.0 as well. Also when we mark an API as deprecated, it still works as expected and it's just an indication to get rid of this API as soon as possible. So I believe the issue is different. Most likely, the ServiceInterop.dll started getting loaded in 1.11.0 for the API you are using and it was not in 1.10.0. We require you to run your applications in 64 bit host process, so somehow your host process is 32 bit and hence you are getting this error.

Comment: In order to fix this, may I know what's the layout of your project/solution in which you are using the DocumentDB library. What are the project types of each of the projects and in which project are you referencing the DocumentDB client library? We should be able to fix this on 1.11.0 itself and you don't have to move back to 1.10.0. Let me know.

Comment: In the sample you pasted, you are using this API: DocumentClient.CreateDocumentQuery Method (Uri, FeedOptions) which is not marked as deprecated. It's the one that takes the partition key as an object which is not your case for the first sample you have.

Comment: @RajeshNagpal As I said, by the current solution (as I mentioned), it is solved. I have no problem any more! Thanks.

Comment: @RajeshNagpal Also, in the first example, FeedOption has a key role in partitioning. Also, I've tested before using from partitionKey in my quer, and it was not worked anymore. Anyhow, you can test it by yourself.

Comment: @OmG I had the same problem and resolved it by downgrading the version to 1.10. Do you know what is the new way to do similar query with 1.11 version?

Comment: I had the same exception when using the 1.11.0 version when using it in an Azure Function. Switching back to 1.10.0 solved the issue.
FYI: I don't think the function is deprecated (copy/pasted the code from the official docs).

Comment: Thanks. The downgrade solved the immediate problem, still wondering what the replacement should look like. The docs do not give a clear indication.

Answer (score 2):

It is assembly version issue and exception also showing the possible solution for fixing.

There are three possible alternates for fixing the same.

1. Change Project Setting in VS2015 -> Tools -> Options - Projects and Solutions -> Web Project and mark tick on "Use 64bit version of IIS..."

[image]

2. Yo can change IIS pool setting and allow 32-bit applications as shown in the image below.

[image]

3. You can also change the project build properties and set the target platform to "Any CPU".

[image]

Comment: Nope! It is not the solution. It should work on Microsoft Azure! There is not access to IIS and something like that! Anyhow, I've done it before on my machine, but changing this configs makes other bugs in compile time, such as conflicts in some dlls in my code, amd my code would have some compile error.

Comment: Work on the version 1.11.1 of document client and activate the option of the first image and work. You created a document as you normally do with this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-dotnetcore-get-started. A question must be made from now on the partitions by docuementos I am not very clear that. Thank you!